# Elasticsearch and query builder: how to get specified field

Tags: elasticsearch, query-builder

I use elasticsearch in my Java Code and I created following search query:

```
 BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("type", "PERSON"));

 SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("private").setQuery(query).execute().actionGet();
```

Above query returns all elements of type "PERSON". Its too much for me because all what I need are values of field "id" of those elements. How to build query which returns only specified "id" field of all elements with type = "PERSON" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("type", "PERSON"));
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("private").setQuery(query).addFields(new String[0]).execute().actionGet();
```